# To execute the AJAX call to ASP.NET WEb Application

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, wcf

Below is my code in code behind in ASP.NET Web Application

```
public string GetData(string name)
    {
        WCF_Web_Service.Service1 client = new WCF_Web_Service.Service1();
        string Name=client.GetData(name);
        return Name;
    }
```

Here I have consumed my simple WCF Service should hive output as Hello,

and below is the my jquery code

```
function asyncServerCall(name) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'WebForm1.aspx/GetData',
            type: "POST",
            data: "{'name':" + name + "}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.d);
            }
        });
    }
```

I have called this function in click event of button as follows

```
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="asyncServerCall(1);" />,
```

I wanted to make AJAX call to call this method from WCF Service, when I click button I get following error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I am novice to use WCF Service and to make AJAx call to evoke its method, any help will be greatly appreciated....

Comment: the exception appears when the Code behind function `GetData` try's to call the WCF or the call doesn't reach the code behind? Have you put breakpoints in the code behind?

Comment: I enterd the breakpoint and checked, I can see WCF service is called and I am getting value in string name but I am not able to make that AJAX call to jquery...

Comment: you mean the response? The problem occurs when WCF returns data to Code Behind or when the Code behind return data to Client side?

Comment: problem occurs when codebehind returns data to the client side..it's not returning data to clientside..

Comment: add error method to the ajax call like this `error: function (result) {
                                alert("Error");
                            }`

Comment: Also try to send a string directly from code behind.

Comment: It's displaying error on the click event of the button and also when I add alert(name); inside the function above jquery.ajax()..its showing 1

Comment: the problem is not when you call the ajax - it is on the response as I understand. An Alert before ajax will be fine. Put the error method like the `success` and try to send a string directly from Code Behind not involving the WCF.

Comment: Can u edit in code to send the string directly from code behind..plz..I am not having idea about it,it will be very grateful of you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `GetData` method needs to be a static web method, so change it to this.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string GetData(string name)
{
    WCF_Web_Service.Service1 client = new WCF_Web_Service.Service1();
    string Name=client.GetData(name);
    return Name;
}
```

[Here's a good article on the why's](http://encosia.com/why-do-aspnet-ajax-page-methods-have-to-be-static/) but essentially it's because:

> This is exactly why they must be marked as static. They cannot interact with the instance properties and methods of your Page class, because a page method call creates no instance of the Page or any of its controls.